# How to set an offset for a RichMarker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Failed enough to ask another question:
Using

- gmaps4rails v0.11.1 - great gem!
- RichMarker

Managed to make markers flat using `:marker_anchor => [10, true]`

But i have an arrow on the bottom of the marker, so how to set an offset for a marker`s html(RichMarker) to be placed?

Now it is done by setting a css offset for a div in the richmarker html. But that seems kind a wierd.

Is it possible to set an offset using Gmaps4rails methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the wiki in the markers section:

```
"rich_marker" =>   ,   # html, facultative
                        # If used, all other attributes skipped except "marker_anchor". This array is used as follows:
                        # [ anchor , flat ] : flat is a boolean, anchor is an int. 
                        # See doc here: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html
```

So basically, the first element of 'marker_anchor => [10, true]' represents the offset.

Have a look at the link I provide: Richmarker's offset aren't expressed with pixels but are integers meaning TOP_LEFT etc...

If you desire precise offset, keep your css!

Comment: There is a problem: RichMarkers DIV is wrapped woith another div from google maps, and whem i`m setting offset for the maker then parent stays on place. 8(((